Is this a good way of fetching data from DB in server components like this?
import { dbConnect } from "@/lib/dbConnect";
import User from "@/models/User";
import Image from "next/image";
import React from "react";
import { MdOutlineExplore } from "react-icons/md";

const Explore = async () => {
  await dbConnect();
  const users = await User.find();

  return (
    <section className="explore">
      <div className="text-2xl font-bold flex items-center gap-x-2">
        Discover People <MdOutlineExplore className="text-yellow-600" />
      </div>
      {users?.map((user, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index} className="user flex gap-x-4 items-center">
            <div className="avatar">
              <Image
                src={user?.avatar ?? ""}
                width={30}
                height={30}
                alt={user?.username}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="details">
              <div className="name">{user?.username}</div>
              <div className="location">{user?.location?.country}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </section>
  );
};

export default Explore;

I was just wondering if this is the best way of fetching the data from DB and displaying it in a server component like this, or do I need to use client comp and a state to store the data?

nope! I think so to get data on a client-side from a database to use getServerSideProps. It is the best feature in Next.js.

I think it depends on your purpose. If you want to secure your db connect and hide some information that needs to get data, the solution above is good enough. If you want to ease your frontend server, feel free to give the user some other safe ways to fetch the data to render on the client side. It will minimize the bandwidth & resources of your frontend server when the active user number increases in the future.
